# Sunfire v100 Reinstall Problems

Tags: solaris, oracle, console

I own two Sunfire v100 servers, and I use hyperterminal to connect to them.

I am trying to re-install Solaris on one of them, so I put in the LOM cable and unplugged the harddrives.

Here's the current console text:

```
LOMlite starting up.

CPU type: H8/3437S, mode 3
Ram-test: 2048 bytes OK
Initialising i2c bus: failed (0xfe held busy)
OK
Searching for EEPROMs: none
Will use eeprom address 50
I2c eeprom @50: failed
i2c bus speed code 00... OK
Probing for lm80s: none
Probing for lm75s: none
System functions: PSUs fans breakers gpio temps host CLI ebus clock
Unexpected reset

LOMlite console
lom>
```

I am trying to get to the OK prompt, through `lom> console` except it says this:

```
Console is not shared
```

I've tried resetting this:

```
lom> bootmode reset_nvram
```

That does nothing, I'm still not able to get into OK for OpenBoot.

Also tried:

```
lom> bootmode forth
```

I will be installing Solaris 11 Text-Version from a CD-ROM in the drive.

Comment: have you considered contacting Oracle support? You've already paid for it.

Comment: Is that CPU even still supported by Solaris 11? I've heard an Oracle Sales guy speaking about Support for USII/III/IV being dropped in Solaris 11. Wish you good luck in getting it to run, though!

Comment: @goo - This thing is from 2003, it's a piece of junk, and I might just sell it on eBay or something.

Comment: @juwi - I will try Solaris 10, but I'm not even able to get to the boot menu because the system itself isn't going to the OK> terminal, 'console' fails to open for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the SCC, or it's damaged.

*You cannot boot a server with a missing / damaged SCC.*

Tell-tale sign;

```
Searching for EEPROMs: none
```

It *should* say something like;

```
Searching for EEPROMs: 50(cfg)
```

[Check the back of the v100](http://tech.cryptzone.com/download/AppGate-9.2.4/appliance/doc/manual_chunked_html/a1-a2-v100.png). There's a big purple credit-card reader thing, called a "System Configuration Card Reader"

Is there a white card zip-tied into it? No?
That's the [EEPROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM) (Electrically Erasable Programmable Read-Only Memory)

Search eBay for "system configuration card". Don't pay more than $20 USD for it.
Shouldn't matter what kind of system it's from. All SCCs were the same form factor and size (to my knowledge).

**Side-Note:** You will not be able to install Solaris 11 on there. Support for that CPU has been discontinued. (All 32-bit support was chopped in Solaris 11, along with the older SPARC64 systems).

If you want to run Solaris 11 on a SPARC, your best bet MIGHT be a T-1000 or T-2000 (haven't tried it, personally).
Stick with Solaris 10 for SPARC.

Solaris 11 x86 runs decent on most newer 64-bit x86 CPUs (I use Virutalbox on a AMD Phantom)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19088-01/v100.srvr/816-2756-10/816-2756-10.pdf) article suggests to get to the ok prompt from lom

```
lom> break
ok>
```

although [this](http://www.sheepguardingllama.com/2007/09/building-a-sunfire-v100-from-the-lom/) article suggests

```
lom> boot forth
lom> poweron
```

will get you to

```
ok>
```

from which you can

```
ok> boot cdrom
```

Comment: Doing the first method pops `Console is not shared` which is my problem. The second thing brings this: `lom>boot forth
lom>poweron
lom>`

Comment: does anything here http://www.sunshack.org/data/sh/2.1.8/infoserver.central/data/syshbk/collections/SRDB/1-25-78349-1.html work ?

Comment: Option 1 is not possible, there is not a functional copy of Solaris. Option 2 failed, was in my original post. Option 3: after resetting, the thing boots up with orange failure light. It did boot up after resetting four times, `System functions: PSUs fans breakers rails gpio temps host CLI ebus clock. Unexpected reset` Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me an

```
environment
```

and a

```
show eventlog
```

from lom, because that output doesn't look very good (come on, it didn't find an EEPROM and I2C failed).
If theres anything interesting in

```
lom -a
```

that might be of interest, too.

Comment: http://fixee.org/paste/45kjmr7/ that's basically all of the info I have here, not much else for me to do with the server at the moment. It's mounted in a cabinet with the LOM cable going to a laptop, and a network cable on port 0 going to a switch with the other servers. `show eventlog` will not show anything else because the server was just reset.

Comment: Mmh... tried a reset_nvram followed by reset, yet?

Comment: Yes sir. `lom>reset
lom>console
Console is not shared
lom>bootmode reset_nvram
lom>reset
lom>bootmode reset_nvram
lom>poweroff
lom>poweron
lom>`

Comment: Got one more:
bootmode -u;
reset;
let it powercycle;
do the jumper

Comment: Results: http://fixee.org/paste/mquxaoh/

Comment: Also: `lom>users
1: [inaccessible]
2: [inaccessible]
3: [inaccessible]
4: [inaccessible]
lom>` That doesn't look good. The config card is in there, I tried all of this both with and without it.

Comment: Yeah, looks pretty bad. No OS on that machine I suppose?

I mean, what we're trying to accomplish here is set the console to ttya, so you can switch to it. Could be done from Solaris via eeprom command. I'm wondering if the problem is that it does not find an EEPORM...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2738/discussion-between-mesh-and-juwi)